# Why is the VM shutting down in android

Tags: android, kotlin, sms

I have a small app which sends an SMS to randomly generated mobile numbers. After about 2,500 SMS messages are sent the VM shuts down and the app bombs out.

Here is the relevant code:

```
package com.example.senddynamicsms

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.telephony.SmsManager
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlin.random.Random
import kotlin.time.measureTime


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var counter = 0
    val begin = System.currentTimeMillis()

    private fun getPermission () {
        val PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
            ) {
                Log.d("permission", "permission denied to SEND_SMS - requesting it")
                val permissions = arrayOf<String>(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
            }
        }
    }
    private fun sendDynamicSMS () {
        val internationalCode = "+44"
        val mobileNetworkCode = "77"
        val i1 = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
        val n1 = i1.toString()
        val i2 = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
        val n2 = i2.toString()
        val i3 = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
        val n3 = i3.toString()
        val i4 = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
        val n4 = i4.toString()
        val i5 = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
        val n5 = i5.toString()
        val i6 = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
        val n6 = i6.toString()
        val i7 = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
        val n7 = i7.toString()
        val i8 = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
        val n8 = i8.toString()
        val number = "$internationalCode$mobileNetworkCode$n1$n2$n3$n4$n5$n6$n7$n8"
        Log.d("", "Trying to send to $number")
        SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, "https://wottot.com/7NoahideLaws.html", null, null)
        counter++
        val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
        Log.d("", "Sent $counter messages in ${(end - begin)/1000} seconds")
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        getPermission()
        while (true) {
            try {
                sendDynamicSMS()
                Log.d("", "Message sent")
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                Log.d("", "Messsage not sent")
            }
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

}
```

Here is relevant output from the log:

```
2022-10-19 17:38:47.990 7690-7690/com.example.senddynamicsms D/: Sent 2179 messages in 165 seconds
2022-10-19 17:38:47.990 7690-7690/com.example.senddynamicsms D/: Message sent
2022-10-19 17:38:47.990 7690-7690/com.example.senddynamicsms D/: Trying to send to +447745204676
2022-10-19 17:38:48.262 7690-7690/com.example.senddynamicsms E/SmsManager: sendTextMessageInternal: Couldn't send SMS, exception - null {x-message-id:0}
2022-10-19 17:38:48.262 7690-7690/com.example.senddynamicsms D/: Sent 2180 messages in 165 seconds
2022-10-19 17:38:48.262 7690-7690/com.example.senddynamicsms D/: Message sent
2022-10-19 17:38:48.262 7690-7690/com.example.senddynamicsms D/: Trying to send to +447703683621
2022-10-19 17:38:48.286 7690-7690/com.example.senddynamicsms D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 145147528; UID 10332; state: ENABLED
2022-10-19 17:38:48.286 7690-7690/com.example.senddynamicsms D/: Sent 2181 messages in 165 seconds
2022-10-19 17:38:48.286 7690-7690/com.example.senddynamicsms D/: Message sent
2022-10-19 17:38:48.286 7690-7690/com.example.senddynamicsms D/: Trying to send to +447783476433
2022-10-19 17:38:48.291 7690-7690/com.example.senddynamicsms D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2022-10-19 17:38:48.295 7690-7690/com.example.senddynamicsms E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.senddynamicsms, PID: 7690
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.senddynamicsms/com.example.senddynamicsms.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Sms is not supported
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4035)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Sms is not supported
        at android.telephony.SmsManager.getISmsServiceOrThrow(SmsManager.java:1762)
        at android.telephony.SmsManager.getSubscriptionId(SmsManager.java:1624)
        at android.telephony.SmsManager.resolveSubscriptionForOperation(SmsManager.java:1649)
        at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessageInternal(SmsManager.java:652)
        at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:489)
        at com.example.senddynamicsms.MainActivity.sendDynamicSMS(MainActivity.kt:52)
        at com.example.senddynamicsms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:61)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8270)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4009)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4201) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135) 
2022-10-19 17:38:48.371 7690-7690/com.example.senddynamicsms I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7690 SIG: 9
```

As you can see the VM shutdown happens some time after a failed SMS send. Could this be related?

`2022-10-19 17:38:48.262 7690-7690/com.example.senddynamicsms E/SmsManager: sendTextMessageInternal: Couldn't send SMS, exception - null {x-message-id:0}`

Why is the VM shutting down? Why does the app bomb out? How can I fix this?

Comment: `Sent 2179 messages in 165 seconds` Sending that many messages from a end-user device in such a short time indicates a 'spam app' which may be throttled by OS or network provider. For legitimate purposes there are paid services for sending SMS to multiple clients.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks for answering. This is not a network provider problem. ```D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM``` seems to indicate that the VM is being shut down by the app itself. Any ideas why?

Comment: Based on `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Sms is not supported` I think you are losing SMS permission. What code is enforcing the rule may depend on what device/emulator/ROM (custom or stock) you are testing on. See: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/telephony/java/android/telephony/SmsManager.java?q=getISmsServiceOrThrow

Comment: @MorrisonChang I'm testing on a Galaxy A12. Sometimes a dialog pops up asking for permission to continue sending SMS messages as the device detects that the app is sending a lot of SMS messages. However, I always hit allow. So I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: Like I said, SMS spam is a problem on Android devices so there are most likely layers of enforcement. If you are testing on a physical device the HAL layer (Radio Interface Layer) may be keeping its own count and block/shutdown further attempts (even if the user or custom ROM allows it). As your code is only for spammers, legitimate uses would not have so many messages per time period (say IoT monitoring).

Comment: @MorrisonChang So the solution is to slow it down? I added a 1000 millisecond ```sleep```. So now it is sending only 1 SMS per second. It has sent 590 in 647 seconds and hasn't bombed out yet. Will let you know in a hour or so if the app manages to keep going.

Comment: @MorrisonChang My latest output says ```Sent 3950 messages in 4297 seconds```. It seems you are right. The problem is related to the speed of the sending of the SMS messages. It seems I need to hack the HAL if I want to be able to send SMS messages at speed. Any ideas where to find the relevant HAL code that is limiting the speed?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to send **every next message** after the previous message was sent, avoiding to use while(true) loop, also **I would check for permissions every time before trying to send each message**, so you could get sure you're not trying to send messages without having the properly persmission.

Unnecesary Plus:

Please move

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

to the beginning of onCreate()

Comment: I tried ```if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
                ){
                    break
                }
            }``` in the while loop to break out if there is no permission to send an SMS. The error persists.